# SwitchCompat onClickListener called for every button in group

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am creating a ListView of switches, dynamically populated from the DB. I need to verify that at least one of them is chosen, and enable / disable a continue button. I am storing the values of the switches in a HashMap so that I can easily check if it contains a true value.

The switches are created in a CursorAdapter, and I have tried both setting an OnClickListener and OnCheckedChangeListener. It seems with both, that when an item is clicked, the listener fires for every button in the list, and the values I am storing in a HashMap are then being overwritten with the checked state of a button further down the list.

```
class LanguageInstallAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private final String LOG_TAG = LanguageInstallAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    public HashMap<String,Boolean> mDBValues = new HashMap<String,Boolean>(); //original DB values
    public HashMap<String,Boolean> mChangedValues = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();//anything changed
    private HashMap<String,Boolean> mAllCurrentValues= new HashMap<String,Boolean>(); //complete current
    private View mRootView;

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public final TextView nameView;
        public final SwitchCompat installSwitch;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.language_textview);
            installSwitch = (SwitchCompat) view.findViewById(R.id.installed_switch);
        }
    }

    public LanguageInstallAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags, View root) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        mRootView = root;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_install_language, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        String languageId = cursor.getString(LanguageInstallFragment.COL_ID);
        String name = cursor.getString(LanguageInstallFragment.COL_NAME);
        boolean langInstalled = cursor.getInt(LanguageInstallFragment.COL_INSTALLED)>0; //convert DB 1 or 0 to java boolean
        mDBValues.put(languageId, langInstalled);
        mAllCurrentValues.put(languageId, langInstalled);
        viewHolder.nameView.setText(name);
        viewHolder.installSwitch.setChecked(langInstalled);
        viewHolder.installSwitch.setTag(languageId);
        viewHolder.installSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CompoundButton button = (CompoundButton) v;
                String buttonLang= (String) button.getTag();
                mChangedValues.put(buttonLang, button.isChecked());
                mAllCurrentValues.put(buttonLang, button.isChecked());
                setSubmitButton();
            }
        });
    }

    public void setSubmitButton(){

        for (Map.Entry<String,Boolean> entry : mAllCurrentValues.entrySet()) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Hashmap: " + entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        }

        if(mAllCurrentValues.containsValue(true)) {
            mRootView.findViewById(R.id.submit_button).setEnabled(true);
            mRootView.findViewById(R.id.lang_prompt).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mRootView.findViewById(R.id.submit_button).setEnabled(false);
            mRootView.findViewById(R.id.lang_prompt).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Log output from a sequence of selections:

```
Initial state (none selected)
09-07 20:21:29.445  ﹕ Hashmap: 4 false
09-07 20:21:29.445  ﹕ Hashmap: 2 false
09-07 20:21:29.445  ﹕ Hashmap: 3 false

Select 2 (1 selected)
09-07 20:22:42.096  ﹕ Hashmap: 4 false
09-07 20:22:42.096  ﹕ Hashmap: 2 true
09-07 20:22:42.096  ﹕ Hashmap: 3 false

Select 3 (2 selected)
09-07 20:23:28.192  ﹕ Hashmap: 4 false
09-07 20:23:28.192  ﹕ Hashmap: 2 false
09-07 20:23:28.192  ﹕ Hashmap: 3 true

Select 4 (3 selected)
09-07 20:23:43.608  ﹕ Hashmap: 4 true
09-07 20:23:43.608  ﹕ Hashmap: 2 false
09-07 20:23:43.608  ﹕ Hashmap: 3 true

Unselect 2 (2 selected)
09-07 20:23:58.507  ﹕ Hashmap: 4 true
09-07 20:23:58.507  ﹕ Hashmap: 2 false
09-07 20:23:58.507  ﹕ Hashmap: 3 false

Unselect 3 (1 selected)
09-07 20:24:13.942  ﹕ Hashmap: 4 false
09-07 20:24:13.942  ﹕ Hashmap: 2 false
09-07 20:24:13.942  ﹕ Hashmap: 3 false
```

Is there a way to not call the listener on every button? Even with the call for each button, why is the value being overwritten incorrectly? Shouldn't the call for each button still be getting the languageId and isChecked value for that button, and not overwriting a different one? Is there a better way to be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line

```
mAllCurrentValues.put(languageId, langInstalled);
```

with

```
if (mAllCurrentValues.contains(languageId)) {
    langInstalled = mAllCurrentValues.get(languageId);        
} else {
    mAllCurrentValues.put(languageId, langInstalled);
}
```

Comment: I called setSubmitButton() at the end of bindView() the with idea of using that to set up the submit button when the list was built. I know it is called redundantly, but I couldn't find anywhere else that would call it when the list was fully built. I found that onLoadFinished() is called before bindView() executes for the list items. That aside, taking the call out here, it still behaves oddly: if I select items, it enables the button, but if I select two or more, then unselect items back to one selected, it behaves as of zero were selected and the logging is similar to above.

Comment: Could you describe more details on your expected behaviour, e.g. what is the expected  log? By looking at the code, the onClickListener should be correctly set, the problem should be in some place else?

Comment: The end behavior to the user would be that the button is enable only when one or more items are selected. To accomplish this, I am putting the boolean value into a HashMap with the languageId as the key. Initially, the values are populated from the database, then they are updated whenever a user selects an item. Thus, I would expect the HashMap values to reflect the values of the switches in the list, and when one or more are in the selected state, the button would be enabled.

Comment: No, it is not working now; I've updated the logging above with a series of selections.

Comment: updated, please check. Seems you reset the record in `mAllCurrentValues` on every `bindView`

Comment: I'll test some more, but this seems to be working. I'm confused as to why, however. Does bindView get called each time an item is selected? If it was overwriting those values, why were all of them not overwritten to the original DB values every time?

Comment: when you scroll around, bindview could be called, the original purpose is to reuse views, and leave only a small amount of views in memory. E.g. you can have a listview of 10000 items, however maybe only 4 of them would be shown on screen, listview and recyclerview do not keep all the 10000 views around to be memory efficient.